# How can I calculate the partial derivative of this parametric function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative, curves

**Given the Function:**

### $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ , $r \in \mathbb{R}.$

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
        x=r\cos(\theta)\\
        y= r\sin(\theta)
    \end{cases}$

---

**Calculate this Partial Derivative:**

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,\theta)}
\end{equation}

---

I do really need some help on this lads, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to search the term "Jacobian matrix", This is the Jacobian of Cartesian to Polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This symbol is shorthand for the Jacobian matrix
$$\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}& \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$